# Spring Boot: Is it possible to separate css, js and template files from .war?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, deployment, war

I have a new spring boot kotlin application deployed to live server by uploading the .war file created by Maven, it is working properly now. However, it seems that the static contents(css, js and template files) are also compressed in this .war file, this creates some issues for me as if I want to change the css on the live server, I have to re-deploy the entire .war file.

So I wonder, is it possible to separate the css/js/template files from the .war file? This way I upload the .war file to the server, and the css/js/template files separately. If I want to change the css or js file, I dont have to redeploy. Thanks, plz lemme know how this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register resource locations outside your WAR, in order for Spring Boot to serve them.

For instance, you can serve all files from the `/opt/files` directory at the `/files/<file_path_relative_to_optfiles_dir>` URL this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class MvcConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/files/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/files/");
    }
}
```

You can have more explanations in [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) (it's in Java but you can get the idea).

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. So if I want the folder from the folder "/resources/static" to be excluded from .war, I just write registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("file:/resources/static/")? This way I can make changes to the static files like .css, .js and .png on the fly, and I will not need to redeploy .war to see changes?

Comment: Doing this is not exactly *excluding* the files from the war, it's rather *including* them from a folder on your machine located at `/resources/static`. But yes, doing so should enable you to just update the files in the directory while the server is running. But you'll need to create that folder on the machine where the war is deployed and put the files there.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was able to load external file on my local machine and remote server. The only issue is that its a little inconvenient that I have to change the resource location when I switch from dev mode to production mode. I wonder, is it possible to specify this in applications.properties file? This way I can divide it into application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties, and easily switch between dev/production mode.

Comment: @LordYggdrasill I'm not sure and haven't tested this, but you should be able to register both an in-war resource location *and* a file-based resource location. Maybe you can register the file-based location with higher priority than the resource-based one, and therefore use in-war resources in dev mode but file-based resources in prod mode (with the bonus side-effect that you have a default value for resources if no files are provided on the server). This needs to be tested, it's just a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

## You can use *external resources* configuration

If you don't want a file to be part of the war package, just put a simple configuration to exclude it:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```